# Why U(1) and SO(2) are locally equivalent?

Tags: group-theory

In one of my particle physics textbooks, I came across the statement that U(1) and SO(2) are locally equivalent. I don’t really know what it means. I know a bit of group theory and that $U(1)$ is just the group of $1$-D unitary transformations and $SO(2)$ the $2$-D proper rotation group.

Could anyone explain the statement in both a formal and intuitive way? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it said something like that involving those two groups?  Usually people talk about $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$ being locally equivalent...

Comment: The two groups are quite different: $U(1)$ is abelian and $1$-dimensional, while $SO(3)$ is non-abelian and of dimension $3$. There is no sensible sense in which the are locally equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been SO(2) instead of SO(3).

Comment: In that case, you can eaiy describe each of the group and see that they are not only «locally equivalent», whatever that may mean, but actually *the same*.

Comment: What Mariano says. The isomorphism is
$$e^{i\phi}\mapsto \pmatrix{\cos\phi&-\sin\phi\cr\sin\phi&\cos\phi}.$$

Comment: By locally equivalent, I believe they're saying the Lie group algebras coincide

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both $U(1)$ and $SO(2)$ are geometrically the circle $S^1$.

$U(1)$ is the set of complex numbers (or $1\times 1$ complex matrices) such that $z\bar{z} = \bar{z}z = 1$.  That is, the set $e^{i\theta}$ for real $\theta$.

$SO(2)$ is the set of rotations in $\mathbb R ^2$.  The rotations $r_\theta$ form a group under composition.

These two groups are isomorphic, and the isomorphism is just the one described by Jyrki: for a complex number $z$ in $U(1)$ the corresponding element in $SO(2)$ is the rotation by the angle which is the argument of $z$.